# Dielectric loss in a substrate

Tags: electromagnetism, microwave

Hey so I am stuck over this question:
[image]

The first part is simple. Since \$\sigma=0\$, therefore \$\alpha=0\$ and \$\beta=\omega\sqrt{\mu\epsilon}\$. \$\epsilon\$ can be found by referring to the datasheet of the board.

What I don't get is the second part. If \$\alpha=0\$ then there should be no attenuation because the factor \$e^{-\alpha x}\$ reduces to 1. Am I right to understand that the electric field will have the same magnitude of 5 mV/m after 50 meters?.

Comment: Sounds like the dielectric losses are finite, and sigma (copper resistivity???) (so conductive losses) is zero. Check what all your terms mean, and what other assumptions the question is making. My 4350 boards are usually smaller than 50m!

Comment: How can I use the dielectric losses to find the attenuation in the electric field?.

Comment: through the \$\alpha\$ term. Presumably you have the board data for 'the losses in the board' referred to in the question?

Comment: No, that is the complete question. I do have the board datasheet though.

Comment: what do you understand is meant by \$\sigma\$ and \$\alpha\$ ?

Comment: \$\sigma\$ is the conductivity, which for this board is given as 0. \$\alpha\$ is the attenuation constant, given in Np/m.

Is this correct.

Comment: I don't know whether it's 'correct', but it's what I thought they meant, at least resisitivty, not conductivity. Conductivty=0 would be very lossy indeed. So as you have a finite attenuation constant, I'm not sure why you write 'as \$\sigma=0\ therefore\ \alpha=0\$', and you have the datasheet, from which you can get \$\alpha\$

Answer (score 1):

*"If α=0 then there should be no attenuation because the factor \$e^{−αx}\$ reduces to 1. Am I right to understand that the electric field will have the same magnitude of 5 mV/m after 50 meters?."*

That's correct. Loss in the dielectric is due to any nonzero conductivity. Here sigma=0, so no loss in the dielectric. In terms of loss tangent, it is zero here, so \$\alpha_d=0\$. In terms of R,L,G,C parameters, dielectric loss is due to G, however G=0 here, so no loss. E field should continue without any change in amplitude, but with only phase change.